# Having trouble following node.js juju docs

Tags: juju, nodejs

I'm trying to follow the [docs here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/howto-node) and I'm running into an issue with this line:

```
juju deploy --config myapp.yaml node-app myapp
```

I've created a `myapp.yaml` file and added a github URL to a sample Node.js app but when I try to run the command I get this:

```
Added charm "cs:precise/node-app-10" to the environment.
ERROR no settings found for "myapp"
```

There's no mention of this possibility in the docs and I'm unable to find anyone mentioning something similar.

I've been able to run other JuJu charms successfully. For instance I've followed the [Getting Started docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started) and everything worked perfectly.

Thanks a ton to anyone who might be able to help.

Comment: It might help to inline the config yaml so one of us can try to reproduce it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is sorely lacking and even outright incorrect on this charm.  The trick here is that you're going to be using that last word on the juju deploy line "myapp" as the unit name rather than "node-app".  The thought would be that you might deploy several different node apps and you need to differentiate them with commands like:  juju status myapp.  Note that we're not using:  juju status node-app.

That said, I ran into problems with all this since I'm not running any Precise nodes, just Trusty ones.  So the documentation doesn't mention anything about this and in my case, it just failed since it couldn't find a suitable node.

Your myapp.yaml then needs to look like this:

```
myapp:
  app_name: myapp
  app_url: http://github.com/mmm/myapp.git
```

You'd want to replace that git URL with your own.  I found that http worked more consistently than https, btw.

You may or may not want to expose your service if you're not using haproxy in conjunction with this.  Note that you might need a config/config.js file in your application which includes variables for mongodb, for example, and which includes the port to use.

A big warning would be that the config-changed hook seems to NOT be able to pull from the git image.  Translation:  this mighty run the install hook correctly, pull your image and start node BUT if the config-changed hook runs THAT code doesn't seem to be able to pull the git image again for some reason.  It just indicates that it can't find the git image on github.  So at the moment, you might find this useful if your code isn't getting revised too much.